# Constraint animation doesnt animate y position change

Tags: swift

This code is to expand a label by disabling the constraint which is keeping it at a max height of 54 to a full size. It works as it should but it jumps to the new y position straight away (without animating) and changes frame height after which makes it look like it jumps before animating

```swift
@IBOutlet var descriptionHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBAction func toggleFullDescription(_ sender: Any) {
        if descriptionHeightConstraint.isActive {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
            descriptionHeightConstraint.isActive = false
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
            //seeMoreButton.setTitle("See less", for: .normal)
        } else {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
            descriptionHeightConstraint.isActive = true
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
            //seeMoreButton.setTitle("See more", for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

[Video of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxdmY.jpg)

Comment: The code you posted doesn't change the X position of your label. It doesn't change anything at all in the horizontal axis.

Comment: But x position is determined by the top constraint? (Which is set to 20px constant)

Comment: Why is the X position determined by the top constraint?

Comment: oh god i mixed y and x